# Firebase Cloud Function works when called via Http but not from scheduled invocation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This function performs some export task:

```js
export const exportDataToStorage = async ()=> {
  const googleCloudFirestore = await import('@google-cloud/firestore')
  const client = new googleCloudFirestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient()
  ...
```

If i run this function http triggered, all works fine, if I trigger it using a schedule like this:

```js
.pubsub.schedule('0 23 * * sat')
  .timeZone('Europe/Berlin')
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    await exportDataToStorage()
  })
```

I get the error `Cannot read property 'FirestoreAdminClient' of undefined` which is unexpected, since it works when called as a http function and also on the local emulator.
Any idea whats the difference when invoking via a schedule?

I am having a hard time debugging this scenario, since it is not clear to me what the difference is when running based on a schedule instead of invoking via http.

Comment: Hi, Can you try using require instead of import? and follow this [Firebase document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#create_a_cloud_function_and_a_job) to write your scheduled function. See if it helps?